# Convert Generic API Response in Blazor

Tags: serialization, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a Blazor WASM project and I'm stuck in this point.

I'm using a DataAccess Service to make the requests to EndPoints;

The endpoints return a ResultList, that is a Generic Object that needs to be parsed in Client side. The object definition:

```
public class ResultList
    {
        public ResultList(List<object> resultados, string codigoErro = null, string mensagemErro = null)
        {
            this.Resultados = resultados;
            this.CodigoErro = codigoErro;
            this.MensagemErro = mensagemErro;
        }

        public string MensagemErro { get; set; }
        public List<object> Resultados { get; set; }
        public string CodigoErro { get; set; }
    }
```

In the client side, I receive the same type:

```
 public async Task<ResultList> GetEmpresas()
        {
            try
            {
                ResultList Result = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ResultList>("api/EmpCadBasico/GetEmpresas");
                return Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ResultList(null, null, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

The problem is: I can't convert the `List<Object>` to other type like `List<Empresa>`.
The C# compilation doesn't notify bug, but in execution time, it happens.

I tried Serialize and Deserialize, and it doesn't work too:

```
public async Task GetEmpresas()
        {
            ResultList Resultado = await _dataAccess.GetEmpresas();

            if (await RetornoOk(Resultado))
            {
                string x = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Resultado.Resultados); // Here, that's fine.
                List<Empresa> y = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Empresa>>(x); // Here, it finds the objects, but all of them with null values.
            }
        }
```

The X value: `'[{"id":1,"nomeEmpresa":"Alamo","cnpj":"00072619000101","dataCadastro":"2020-01-01T00:00:00","colaborador":[],"marca":[]}]'`

The Y value: [Y value after Deserialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRFjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the json return data you provided, I did the following restoration and successfully returned the data, you can refer to it.

Model:

```
public  class TestModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nomeEmpresa { get; set; }
       public string cnpj { get; set; }
        public string dataCadastro { get; set; }

        public List<colaborador> colaborador { get; set; }

        public List<marca> marca { get; set; }

    }

    public class colaborador
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

    public class marca
    {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

Then I gave values to individual attributes, and the results are as follows：
[image]